# com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 73: 'Invalid database name: '"test" even though database exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and Mongodb.In the below code I am trying to create a sample Rest API to insert a document in mongodb.
But when i try to connect to database the below exception is thrown.

> **com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 73: 'Invalid database name: '"test"'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Invalid database name: '\"test\"'", "code" : 73, "codeName" : "InvalidNamespace" }*

Even though there is database by name test exists: -
[Database list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ppPs.png)

The below is the request url defined of type post with JSON data: -

```
http://localhost:8080/start
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"aa"
}
```

The controller: -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/start",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<DemoDocument> pageload(@RequestBody DemoDocument demodocument)
    {
        demoService.pageload(demodocument);
        return new ResponseEntity<DemoDocument>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The service layer: -

```
@Service
public class DemoService {

    @Autowired
    DemoRepository demoRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void pageload(DemoDocument demodocument) 
    {
        demoRepository.insert(demodocument);
    }

}
```

the pojo class: -

```
public class DemoDocument {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
   // getters and setters
}
```

The repository layer: -

```
@Repository
public interface DemoRepository extends MongoRepository<DemoDocument, String>{

}
```

The application.properties file: -

```
spring.data.mongodb.database="test"
```

Kindly explain me what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should that not be `spring.data.mongodb.database=test` without the quotes `""`.

Comment: Thank you it worked unfortunately I wasn't able to find that small mistake

Comment: Properties files work out such details for you. The error message was also actually telling you the problem as  `\"test\"` shows the escaped quotes which of course should not be there. Just for future reference.

Comment: ok sure will keep that in mind from now on.